# How to get last insert row id using MySqlOperator

Tags: python, mysql, airflow

I have a table in MySQL which has a column called id (auto-increment), status ('running', 'failed', 'success') and others, and I want to author a DAG which starts by inserting a row in this table, and after some other task I want at the end update this same row with a new status.

How can I get the last inserted row id from MySqlOperator?

```
mysql = MySqlOperator(task_id='task_name', sql='insert into table (status, others) VALUES ('running', other)')
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try to get the last insert id after your query:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name (status, others) VALUES ('running', other);
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

and to ensure getting the right id:

```sql
START TRANSACTION;
  INSERT INTO table_name (status, others) VALUES ('running', other);
  SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
COMMIT;
```

Then the operator should return the result as a XCom, you can access it by `"{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='task_name') }}"`